# Rails & Devise - how to determine when a user is logging out?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

In my Rails app, I have some `after_commit` ... `on: :update` callbacks that are responsible for doing some work after a user updates their account settings.

Trouble is that these callbacks get triggered when a user logs out. I checked to see what's being updated on the user by calling `self.previous_changes`, and here's the output:

`=> {"remember_created_at"=>[Wed, 06 May 2020 20:32:09 UTC +00:00, nil], "updated_at"=>[Thu, 07 May 2020 14:52:42 UTC +00:00, Thu, 07 May 2020 14:54:40 UTC +00:00]}`

So as you can see a logout clears `"remember_created_at"` and updates `"updated_at"`.

I could make a method on the user called `is_logging_out?` that checks for these two changed attributes and returns true, but that feels hack-y and I was wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this.

(In case it matters I'm on devise v3.5.10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model callbacks have this drawback. I strongly promote not using model callbacks in favour of Decorators or explicit invokation. 
However, if you are sure you need this callback, then why not try skipping the callback unless `remember_created_at` is not nil?

```
def your_callback_method
  return unless remember_created_at

  #do stuff
end
```

You could either skip it in the callback method itself or add `if: -> { record.remember_created_at }` to the `after_commit` declaration

Please do not add a method called `is_logging_out?` in the model because this is not model responsibility. The model should not depend on what the user ongoing action is.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to be using model callbacks in the first place? They are by their nature hacky and it usually becomes an increasingly difficult struggle to control when and where they are fired.

If you just override the controller you know exactly where this logic will be fired and it won't slow down your tests or create more unexpected bugs down the line.

```
class UsersController < Devise::SessionsController
  def update
    super do |user|
      # do something awesome
    end
  end
end
```

```
devise_for :users, controller: {
  registrations: 'my_sessions'
}
```